# Swift Send Hex Data Over TCP Socket

Tags: swift, sockets, tcp, hex

I'm working on a solution to send commands to a point of sale receipt printer and having some issues getting the command format right.  Ive got a socket open to the device and thats working, because incorrect commands are printed.  What the SPEC calls for in this command is to send the following:

1B 07 or in decimal 27 7.  Which in ASCII is ESC_KEY BEL.  The only example the spec shows is for .NET:

MSComm1.Output = Chr$(&H1B) & Chr$(&H07)

What I've been trying:

// Socket is open previously using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost.

```
var cmd = "27 07"
if let dataString = "\(cmd)\r".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false), let oStream = self.outputStream {
        self.outputData.append(dataString)

        if oStream.hasSpaceAvailable {
            oStream.write(UnsafePointer((self.outputData.first! as NSData).bytes), maxLength: self.outputData.first!length)
        }
    }
```

The data is getting there, but I think the format of the message is wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you send to the printer is the byte sequence 0x50, 0x55, 0x32, 0x48, 0x55, 0x13.   your printer is waiting for the byte sequence 0x1b, 0x07

Answer (score 3):

Just create a byte (aka `UInt8`) array with the data that you want
to send, and pass that directly to the `write()` method of `NSOutputStream`:

```
let cmd: [UInt8] = [0x1B, 0x07]
oStream.write(cmd, maxLength: cmd.count)
```

Note that you send *bytes* to the output stream, not *hex data*.
It makes not difference at all if you create the array with hexadecimal
integer literals as above, or as

```
let cmd: [UInt8] = [27, 7]
```

the data is exactly the same.

Comment: Not enough rep to upvote, but this worked perfectly.  Thanks!